# How to organize technical skills on resume?

Tags: resume, technology, tech-industry

How would I organize the technical skills I have on my resume? This is what I have but I'm not sure if this is the best way to organize.

Skills

Programming Language — C, C++, Objective-C, Python

Web — HTML/5, CSS/3, JavaScript, PHP, JSON, REST

Development Tools — Git, Xcode, Visual Studios, Eclipse

Platforms — UNIX, iOS

Comment: That's fine. You want this section at the top to get you passed HR (which this will do as they tick off all the keywords they need). But the hiring manager will read past that and look at the experience.

Comment: There is no best way.

Answer (score 2):

That's a fine way to list a large number of skills, useful for resumes scanners (either electronic or human) who are comparing your resume against a desired list of hard skills.

If you are applying in response to a job description with a specific set of required skills, you'll want to highlight those skills above the others and add relevant details such as level (e.g. expert) or length (e.g. 3 years) of experience with the technology.

In general the priorities are: (1) make it clear you have exactly what they're looking for and then (2) briefly include your other skills in case they provide additional value.